# When to move data to HDFS/Hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

So I'm developing an application that is expected to deal with large amounts of data, and as such I've decided to use Hadoop to process it.

My services node and datanodes are separated from the webapp, so I'm using HttpFS to communicate the app with Hadoop.

So, whenever a new *row* of data is generated in my application, should I already call the corresponding HttpFS URL to append the data to an HDFS file? Should I write this data in a file in the webserver and using a cronjob upload it to HDFS for example every hour?
Should I have the Hive table updated or should I just load the data in there whenever I need to query it?

I'm pretty new to Hadoop so any link that could help will also be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer below approach.

1. Do not call HtpFS URL to append data to HDSF file for every row update. HDFS is efficient when data file size is more than 128 MB (in Hadoop 2.x) or 64 MB (in Hadoop 1.x)
2. Write the data in web server. Have a rolling appender when file size reaches certain limit - in multiples of 128 MB e.g 1 GB file.
3. You can have hourly based cron jobs but make sure that you are sending big data file (e.g 1 GB or multiple of 128 MB) instead of just sending the log file, which is accumulated in 1 hour.
4. Regarding loading of data, you can use internal or external HIVE tables. Have a look at this [article](http://hortonworks.com/blog/four-step-strategy-incremental-updates-hive/)

Comment: Thanks! This was very useful. Could you please explain a little bit how to configure oozie for this 4-step process? I find it a little confusing with all the config files and stuff

Comment: I am learning and practicing hadoop the definitive guide, chapter by chapter. It may take 1 or 2 weeks for mastering oozie